# How do I remove log out, reboot, and shut down from GNOME shell application list?

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview

I’m new to Ubuntu. I don't know where the log out, reboot and shut down icons in my application list came from. I just need to remove this from here.

[image: Activities window]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If we talking about these gray colored icons:

[image: Logout] [image: Reboot] [image: Shutdown]

then they are provided by [`session-shortcuts` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/session-shortcuts/filelist).

We can hide them by copying to current user settings folder and then adding [property `NoDisplay=true`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys) here:

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/
cp /usr/share/applications/{logout,reboot,shutdown}.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
echo "NoDisplay=true" | tee -a ~/.local/share/applications/{logout,reboot,shutdown}.desktop > /dev/null
```

then logout (and login again) or reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt purge session-shortcuts
```

Logout and then login again.