# How to remove black icons (Lock Screen, Log Out, Power Off, Suspend, Switch User) from GNOME Dash?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell

When I use search on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME Shell I see the following icons among others:

[image: Power Off, Lock Screen, Log Out, Suspend]

[image: Switch User]

How can I hide them? Are they hard-coded somewhere?

Note: this question is not duplicate of ["How do I remove, log out, reboot and shut down from here?"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1077028/66509) asked today, as icons are black (not gray). It is logical continuation of it, but not duplicate.

Comment: I thought that seemed a bit coincidental ;) now you have me curious. it's weird how they cannot be right clicked like the other launchers...

Comment: The difference in colour may be due to a different theme, are you sure not a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks, but no. When [helping to improve the answer of the "duplicate"](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1077030/4) I have had both side by side (as I manually installed `session-shortcuts` package, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJdlA.png)). So currently we are talking about black-and-white icons which are available out-the-box.

Comment: Ah, yes, right. They grey ones look like the ones found in Unity.

Comment: definitely different... further investigation if I open activities window and click all, I see a list of apps... this list DOES NOT include the aforementioned power buttons... they only show when searching and there is no corresponding desktop file that I can find

Comment: The gray ones are installed by session-shortcuts, and that came with Unity. I do not have that package installed by default. Indeed, the black ones are not implemented through adding .desktop files. "Hardcoded", until further notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the  [gnome-shell-extension Hide System Actions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3246/hide-system-actions/)  that will hide the below entries from Gnome's overview search..

[image]

[image]

Comment: can't you just hide it ?