# What is the exact path of black icons like Lock Screen, Log Out, Power Off, Suspend, Switch User created from GNOME Dash?

Tags: 20.04

When I use search on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with GNOME Shell I see the following icons among others:

[image: poweroff icons]

How can I get the exact path of creating power icons ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove black icons (Lock Screen, Log Out, Power Off, Suspend, Switch User) from GNOME Dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077057/how-to-remove-black-icons-lock-screen-log-out-power-off-suspend-switch-user)

Comment: @N0rbert current question is not about removing these black icons, but on where to find them. I do not see that answered in the question you marked as diplicate.

Answer (score 2):

These icons are stored under `/scalable/actions` in the icon folder of your theme. For the default theme of Ubuntu, "Yaru", you will find these icons under `/usr/share/icons/Yaru/scalable/actions`. Their names are like `system-*-symbolic.svg`, e.g. `system-reboot-symbolic.svg`.