# Shutdown, Reboot and Logout buttons in the GNOME App Launcher

Tags: gnome-shell, unity-tweak-tool

I somehow have added buttons for Shut Down, Reboot and Logout into the app launcher in Ubuntu. This is a pretty fresh install of Ubuntu and it wasn't there when I started. If I had to pinpoint one moment this started, I would say it MIGHT be when I accidentally tried to install Unity Tweak Tool not realising I am using a GNOME desktop (it was late, I was tired...). This did result in a bunch of things being installed like Rhythmbox which I have since removed, but these buttons can't be removed as far as I can tell. Has anyone seen this before? Can you suggest what might remove these useless buttons?

[image: App Launcher with unwanted buttons]

Comment: you are rite.. it was by installing additional packages.. have you tried the way you installed in the sameway to uninstall? if `sudo apt install xyz` `sudo apt purge xyz`??

Comment: Unfortunately yes, the last couple lines of the command print 'Package 'unity-tweak-tool' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.'

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the terminal output of `ls ~/.local/share/applications/`? The files to delete will likely be found in that directory.

Comment: I didn't get an output at all. I modified it to `ls -l ~/.local/share/applications/` and got 'total 0'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove log out, reboot, and shut down from GNOME shell application list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077028/how-do-i-remove-log-out-reboot-and-shut-down-from-gnome-shell-application-list) `session-shortcuts` package should be the culprit.

Comment: Please look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` to find which packages dependencies the `Unity tweak tool` have installed --- Desktop app launchers can be found there `/usr/share/applications`